# Finding time periods in VBA

Tags: vba

```
Date        Time    Variable
2011.01.02  22:22   1258.25
2011.01.02  22:24   1258.5
2011.01.02  22:26   1258.25
2011.01.02  22:27   1258.25
2011.01.02  22:28   1258.5
2011.01.02  22:29   1258.5
2011.01.02  22:31   1258.5
2011.01.02  22:32   1260.5
2011.01.02  22:33   1259.75
2011.01.02  22:34   1259.75
2011.01.02  22:37   1259.75
2011.01.02  22:38   1260
2011.01.02  22:39   1260.25
2011.01.02  22:40   1260
2011.01.02  22:43   1259.75
2011.01.02  22:44   1259.5
2011.01.02  22:47   1259.75
2011.01.02  22:48   1260
2011.01.02  22:52   1259.75
2011.01.02  23:10   1259.75
2011.01.02  23:12   1260
2011.01.02  23:13   1260.25
2011.01.02  23:14   1260.25
2011.01.02  23:15   1260.5
2011.01.02  23:16   1260.5
2011.01.02  23:17   1260.25
```

Hey guys,

I have a time series data in excel, and I would like to search for all "time" values that start with 23:xx (23 hour) and select that cell. Instead what I am getting is VBA selecting any cell that that have time "XX:23" (23rd minute)

Assuming I have my active cell on the "Time" column, I am using this code, buts its not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Find("23:", lookat:=xlPart).Select
```

Followup Question:

Also another quick question Doug, I would like to be able to find all the data points that start with "23:XX" the 23rd hour, find the first value and the last value, highlight everything in between and name it as a range.

I was thinking of a "Do" statement to cycle through the cells after the first "23:XX" is found

```
Do
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until Left(ActiveCell) = "23:"
```

but it seems the "Left" function recognizes the cells as numeric, not as a time formated cell? What should I do? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Lookin` argument of the `FIND` function specifies whether to look at the "Formula" - the text that you see in Edit Mode - or`Value` - what's displayed in the cells.  Your `FIND` function is looking in the formulas, so it sees the "11:10 PM" within the cell.  Change it to look in the values, like so:

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell..End(xlDown)).Find("23:", lookat:=xlPart,lookin:=xlvalues).Select
```

Comment: +1 Doug. I was about to suggest using `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat `

Comment: Thanks Dave.  That's an interesting idea.  I tried, but can't figure out how to make it work in Excel, much less VBA.  What would the formula look like? (Find by format is one of those features I forget about.)

Comment: I meant in conjunction with the `Find`, ie `Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "h:mm"
Set rng1 = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Find("11:", lookat:=xlPart)`. Your approach is much better.

Comment: Doug the problem with changing the time variable to values is they become decimals. 23:05 becomes = .95236. I cannot recognize that. What should I do if the cells values are numeric values but the format is displaying a time? Is there a way to adjust the find function?

Comment: Did you try my solution with your data as it is?  I'm not suggesting you change your data, but that you change your formula to what I showed in my answer.  If that doesn't work, please describe your times more, as I may be missing something.

Comment: Sorry Doug, my apologies it did work. Thank you very much! So what did the Xlvalues do to the code? Did it tell excel cell as if it were being seen by a human user and not for its actual value?

Comment: I edited my answer to try to explain, although it's hard to be clear :).  Basically, in both Excel and VBA you can choose to look at the Values, which is a bit misleading, as it's actually what you see in Edit mode, even if it's not a formula, or the value, which is the value displayed in the cell.

Comment: sorry Doug, just deleted it, still learning the rules of the forum, my apologies. What counts more a check or a point up?

Comment: No worries! You should be sble to do both.  Upvote is 10, accept is 15.